# ¿como pasar diccionarios de objetos a JSON?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

por ejemplo tengo dos clases, uno del objeto y otra del diccionario:

```
class objeto:
`  def __init__(self, nombre, edad, peso):
         self.nombre = nombre
         self.edad = edad
         self.peso = peso

class Diccionario:
   def __init__(self):
       self.lista = {}

   def agregar(self, nombre, edad, peso):
       self.lista[nombre] = Objeto(nombre,edad,peso)
```

ahora quisiera guardar ese diccionario en un JSON para luego leerlo de nuevo y no se pierda la lista, pero me genera error al guardar ese diccionario
lo estoy guardando asi:

```
def guarda(self):
    with open('lista.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(self.lista,f, indent =3)
```

Comment: cuando haces `self.lista[nombre] = Objeto(nombre,edad,peso)` estás guardando la instancia del objeto creado en un dict, pero en si no es un "objeto" que contiene información del tipo clave:valor, no se si me hago entender.

Comment: Como podrían hacerlo como tu dices bro? Porque debo siempre guardar la lista

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres guardar los atributos de un objeto, **Python almacena los atributos de los objeto como un diccionario**, por lo que la forma más fácil de hacerlo es llamando al **atributo especial** `.__dict__`, **demostración** de esto:

```
class Objeto:
    def __init__(self, nombre, edad, peso):
            self.nombre = nombre
            self.edad = edad
            self.peso = peso

obj1 = Objeto("Jorge", "34", "69")
obj1.__dict__
```

**Salida:**

```
obj1 = Objeto("Jorge", "34", "69")
```

#### Solución del problema

Para guardar los parámetros del objeto como otro diccionario de claves y valores usamos el parámetro `default` que tiene la función `dump()` y le indicamos que el valor a guardar son los atributos del objeto mediante una función `lambda`. Tú método `guarda()` quedaría así:

```
def guarda(self):
    with open('lista.json', 'w') as f:
    #Le indicamos con default y __dict__ que vaya a los atributos del objeto y los guarde como valor
        json.dump(self.lista, f, default=lambda cls: cls.__dict__ ,indent=3)
```