# ¿Cómo guardo un diccionario en un archivo .json?

Tags: python

¿Cómo puedo guardar unos datos que se almacenan en un diccionario en un archivo .json pero de una manera ordenada en especifico?

Tengo un código que pide informacion por medio de unos inputs y la amaceno en un diccionario para luego guardarlo en un archvo json, sin embargo, al abrir el .json no lo muestra como se supone debería hacerlo.

```
activo = f'| {Id} | {area1} | {equipo} | {marca} | {modelo} | {serial} | {ubi} | {name}{q}{lname}' 
activo1 = {
            'id': {Id},
            'area': {area1},
            'Equipo': {equipo},
            'marca': {marca},
            'modelo': {modelo},
            'serial': {serial},
            'ubicación': {ubi},
            'responsable': {"nombre" : {name} , "apellido" : {lname}}
           }
```

Sucede que quiero que me lo muestre como esta en el código, por lineas, y no todo junto en un solo renglón.

Answer (score 0):

Con el módulo `json` se puede hacer de forma muy fácil

```py
import json

activo1 = {
            'id': Id,
            'area': area1,
            'Equipo': equipo,
            'marca': marca,
            'modelo': modelo,
            'serial': serial,
            'ubicación': ubi,
            'responsable': {"nombre" : name , "apellido" : lname}
           }

with open('archivo.json', 'w') as file:
    json.dump(activo1, file, indent=4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar con `json.dumps` y luego leer con `json.load`:

```
import json

with open("archivo.json", "w") as archivo:

    d = {"clave1":"valor1", "clave2": "valor2"}
    json.dump(d, archive, indent=2)
```

Y luego leer con:

```
with open("archivo.json") as archivo:

    d = json.load(archivo)
    print(d)
```

Y si quieres ver lo que guardó en el archivo `archivo.json`:

```
$ cat archivo.json
{
  "clave1": "valor1",
  "clave2": "valor2"
}
```

Comment: si usas el método `dump` le puedes pasar el propio archivo como objeto (resultante del manage context) y ya no recurres a usar `.write`

Comment: No sabía. Gracias. Actualizaré mi respuesta

Answer (score 0):

De salida ese no es un diccionario válido para ser convertido a JSON. No estás respetando el formato `key:value` en los valores de `id`, `area`, etc

**Mal**

```
data = {
    'area': {area1},
    'Equipo': {equipo},
    'marca': {marca}, 
    # ...
    'responsable': {"nombre" : {name} , "apellido" : {lname}}
}
```

Esto arrojará el siguiente error cuando se intente escribir en un archivo JSON:
 `TypeError: Object of type set is not JSON serializable`

**Bien**

```
data = {
    'area': area1,
    'Equipo': equipo,
    'marca': marca, 
    # ...
    'responsable': {"nombre" : name , "apellido" : lname}
}
```

Ahora es solo cuestión de:

```
with open('tu_archivo.json', 'w') as jf: 
    json.dump(data, jf, ensure_ascii=False, indent=2)
```

Comment: Gracias, si se me soluciono el problema de arriba, sin embargo, aun sigo viendolo todo en un renglón

Comment: @user244713, que extraño. Con el parámetro `indent=2` deberías ver tu archivo indentado. Podrías actualizar tu respuesta y añadir un ejemplo de como adaptaste tu código junto con la salida?

Comment: Listo, cuando lo tenga lo hago. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Creo que no hay mejor respuesta que la dada por Rubiales Alberto en la siguiente pregunta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/412380/25273

```
def guarda(self):
    with open('lista.json', 'w') as f:
    #Le indicamos con default y __dict__ que vaya a los atributos del objeto y los guarde como valor
        json.dump(self.lista, f, default=lambda cls: cls.__dict__ ,indent=3)
```